# If Statement Based Off DATETIME in Shopify header.liquid

Tags: datetime, shopify, liquid

I am trying to add an if-then statement based off a date and time to my `header.liquid`.

I understand PHP and Javascript but am new to liquid and what shopify will allow.

Basically trying to display an image only during a specific date and time:

```
If datetime > 2019-09-06 00:00:00 PST AND < 2019-09-09 00:00:00 PST 
THEN {show image}
```

(Show image from 9/6 PST thru 9/9 PST)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date  --- eg `new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00');`

Comment: @Hogan can't we do this server side to serve image?  That would be my ideal situation rather than waiting for javascript to load on every page then serving an image or not.

Comment: Is there any specific element on Shopify you are trying to compare?

Comment: Todd -- you did not tell us anything about what you are doing server side so there is no way for me to answer this question.  For the question you asked -- about javascript i gave you an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to use the epoch time tag `%s`

On Shopify you can convert any date to epoch using the above `{{ some_datetime_variable | %s }}` and for current time it'd be `{{ "now" | %s }}`

More details - [Dates in liquid](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/date/)